# Discard rows that do not have 6 doublequotes

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a CSV file that has some errors in it. What I want to do is disregard all lines that do not have 6 double quotes (") in them.

So in short it should be something like;

```
cat output.txt | grep -v '"*"*"*"*"*"'
```

Of course the above command won't work.. but it's a direction I am thinking.. maybe AWK would be a better option?

Comment: adding sample input with lines to retain and discard will help... do you want to retain lines with exactly six double quotes? or is it at least six? and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is glob pattern not regex pattern.

You can use this regex in `grep`:

```
grep -Ev '^([^"]*"){6}' file
```

Using awk you can do by using `"` as input field separator:

```
awk -F '"' 'NF<7' file
```